# How do I support the touch of the navigation bar label?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have an [editor](http://github.com/iaefai/Simple-Edit) that I am making, and I need a way of editing the document's title. I was considering touching the title of the navigation item and have a custom view appear.

I did this in an initial version of the application with a button bar item (and target/action), but I cannot seem to find a way to do it with the managed navigation bar.

The alternative I was considering was putting another bar at the bottom with an item to do just that, but it doesn't seem like the best design if I don't need to do it, as it takes away from viewing space.

[image: Example image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `titleView` property of the view controller's `navigationItem` to a `UIButton` of type Custom.  Then wire the button up to a method on the view controller.  Now when the user taps the title, it'll fire the method on your controller.

Comment: I considered that, however in the documentation it says for that property: 

    This property is ignored if leftBarButtonItem is not nil.

I have a back button, so that should be ignored.

Comment: My solution I think is going to have to be using the title of the document in a prompt section (fixes the problem of a long title because of the smaller text), and use a segmented control. I have tested this, and I believe it proves the documentation isn't right.